# Как задать глобальный include для асинхронных скриптов?

Tags: ajax, php

В начале страницы инклудится файл с классом и создается объект

- Ситуация 1 - через $.load()
     подгружается одна из нескольких
     страниц с содержимым.
- Ситуация 2 -
     ajax-запрос к скриптам управления бд

Как сделать, чтобы в этих внешних файлах были видны инклуд и обьект? $GLOBALS не помогает

Comment: Идите учите основы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, создайте файл со всеми необходимыми действиями, инклудами, и в каждом "внешнем" файле делайте инклуд этого файла.